# C# - Creating a 'var' array of a fixed size?

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to create an array of type var with a fixed length. I'm using it in a var Linked List class that I created. I know the size of the array I want to create, don't know what's the correct syntax?

Here's the code:

```
public dynamic ToArray()
{
    int counter = 0;

    if (this.head == null)
        return null;
    else
        counter = 1;

    ListEntry i = this.head;
    while (i.Next != null)
    {
        counter++;
        i = i.Next;
    }

    var array = new[counter];

    i = this.head;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
    {
        array[j] = i.Data;
        i = i.Next;
    }

    return array;
}
```

This part doesn't work:

```
var array = new[counter];
```

Any help?

EDIT: Thank you for the input everyone. I must admit that I wasn't very knowledgeable about the terminology of syntactic sugar when I posted. It now makes more sense.

The idea behind this post was to create a dynamic Linked List class that could handle basic value types.

Comment: You haven't said what *type* of array you want. If you have `var array = new string[counter]` or something like that, it'll be fine.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "type `var`", unless this is a custom type you defined (which would be a crazy bad idea).

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he misunderstands `var` (due to statement: "create an array of type var")...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Ah, true - I'd missed that bit.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the LinkedList<T> that's part of the framework? (and that has ToArray() via IEnumberable)

Comment: @JonSkeet and ReedCopsey I must admit that I didn't have a very good understanding of var meant and the use of syntactic sugar in C#. I was trying to create a versatile LinkedList class for different types. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Linky I've created this class as a part of an assignment in school. It's much simpler and easy to use. And I'm not entirely sure how to use the LInkedList<T> class properly. I tried learning to use it but wasn't very successful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm trying to create an array of type var

`var` is not a type, it's just a *syntactic sugar* for [`implicit type definition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).You need to specify your array type:

```
var array = new YourType[counter];
```

With using `var` you let the compiler to infer the type.But in this case it works like a *shortcut*.Anyway it's useful when you are not sure about the returning type of an expression or method (for example it's useful when using `LINQ`).

```
var array = new[counter];
```

In this line if you mean to create an array that can contains any type of element you can create an array of `objects` or `dynamic`:

```
 var array = new object[counter];
```

Or:

```
 var array = new dynamic[counter];
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
var array = new dynamic[counter];
```

However I am not sure why you want to use `dynamic` here and return a `dynamic` from your method. You probably already know the type of `ListEntry.Data` - you would probably want to return an array of that type.

Comment: If he does want to return a `dynamic`, say for example, because `ListEntry.Data` is dynamic, he probably really wants to return a `dynamic[]`.

Comment: @JoelRondeau: `because ListEntry.Data is dynamic` - agreed. As far as compiler is concerned, if the method defines returning `dynamic` he could return anything including `dynamic[]`. But what you suggest will make code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the array type, or it's like going to a sweet shop and saying "can I have a bag of" and not saying what type you would like, in this case to the compiler. To declare an array, you can do

```
var array = new type[counter];
```

However, you cannot create a var array, as var is not a type, but a keyword used in place of a type, like C++11s auto. You will have to define a specific type for your array or you will hit problems.

For your case, you need a `dynamic` or `object` array.

```
var array = new dynamic[counter];
```

Or

```
var array = new object[counter];
```